# How to get the date in MM/DD format with datetime2?

Tags: datetime

Probably straightforward, but it eluded me so far.

```
\documentclass[
12pt
%,draft
]{report}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[en-US]{datetime2}

\begin{document}
\DTMdate{2020-02-19} % 02/19/2020
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it what you want?

```
\documentclass[
12pt
%,draft
]{report}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[datesep=/, style=mmddyyyy]{datetime2}

\begin{document}

\DTMdate{2020-02-19} % 02/19/2020

\end{document}
```

[image]